# Log Laravel is publicly accessible

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Okay, maybe I'm overlooking something. But we do have kind of a big problem. our Laravel log **`(storage/log/laravel.log)`** is publicly accessible.

The way people can access the log is when they go to **`domain.com/storage/log/laravel.log`** .

I can't find a real solution but I'm sure this is a problem not everybody is facing. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: This is a server issue not Laravel specific issue, you need to share NGINX configuration or Apache configuration instead. While you are at editing, tag the question properly.

Comment: This is an issue in your server configuration. You should NEVER expose anything above the public folder. This means your `.env` file is also accessible which is even more dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that your web root directory for your website is not configured properly, which is a **major vulnerability** in a Laravel application for more reasons than just the public log file. The document root of your website should be the `public/` subdirectory of your Laravel project, *not* the project folder itself.

For example, if your Laravel project's code is in located in `/var/www/example.com/` then your DocumentRoot for Apache should be `/var/www/example.com/public`.

For Nginx, the directive would be `root /var/www/example.com/public;`

For IIS, the "Physical Path" setting would be something like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\public`

If your hosting provider uses a control panel, look through the settings for the document root.

Comment: if root is the parent of "/public" like  "/var/www/example.com/"  instead of "/public" itself, how can this be a vulnerability, how can it be exploited ? what is the difference between both?

Comment: @Omar anything in your storage would be accessible, which includes your log files that may have sensitive information like database credentials. If there are private user files in storage, then any access controls in place can be bypassed. If you have not configured environment variables, then it's likely your `.env` file is accessible as well, which includes the key used to encrypt everything (including session cookies) and credentials for every service your site uses. Depending on your application there may be other sensitive files like encryption keys or configs stored in various locations.

Answer (score 0):

Do not place your Laravel Application in publicly accessible folder (public_html folder for cpanel server). It causes security issues and provides access to your credentials, files, and folders. You may want to follow these steps to host your laravel application.

1. Place your laravel application in a folder that is not accessible publicly.
2. Copy the public folder under your laravel application to your publicly accessible folder (e.g public_html folder under cpanel)
3. Edit index.php file in the public folder as follows: `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`  change the path to reflect your laravel application folder e.g `require __DIR__.'/../../datanow_api/vendor/autoload.php';`  where datanow_api is the folder where your laravel application is placed. Also change `$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';`  to reflect your laravel application folder as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in tour htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "(env|json|lock|css|js|log|xml|yaml|sqlite)">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```

If you want Block Direct access to folder

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all
```

Comment: add the file extensions which need to prevent from direct accessing not only log

Comment: This answer is **dangerous** because it only appears to fix the problem, but leaves *many* other obvious vulnerabilities. Examples off the top of my head include xml, yaml, sqlite, ssh keys, session files, and private uploads in the storage directory. Blacklists are difficult to maintain and always leave something out; the proper solution is to only allow files in the public directory to be served.

Comment: he just asked how to hide log files that's it

Comment: If You want To hide the Session Files from direct Accessing use chmod to change the directory Permissions

Comment: @Manojkiran.A You can continue adding file extensions to the blacklist if you wish, but we'll be here for a year going back and forth adding new file extensions, directories, etc. to the deny list. You are correct that it prevents the log file from being served, but my point in bringing up those examples was that this specific solution is *dangerous* because it fixes symptoms without correcting the vulnerability, which is the incorrectly configured webserver. I wouldn't want somebody to use it and think they had fixed the problem while leaving so many other easy to find holes.

Comment: That is upto the hosting service provider

Comment: Ok I agreed Then If you know How To Do it then go on and answer

Comment: You can make a PR in github in laravel framework to fix this Because Laravel Ships With Default htaccess

Comment: @Manojkiran.A thank you for the suggestion, and I have posted an answer (it looks like 30 minutes before yours? Maybe that's why you didn't see it). Hope it helps!